# net use working without username and password, but when I define them, it gave System error 87 has occurred

Tags: windows, powershell, session, rundeck, network-share

I'd like to use network share mount on the following way.

I have my base64 encoded user password, my user and the network share location.
I'd like to open a ps session, because network share is accessible only from pssession via a user if I ran it from a remote execution application (rundeck).

```
$Securepassword = "password"
$User = ".\user"
$Password = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($SecurePassword))
$Encpassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User,$Encpassword)
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$pp = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $User,$pw
$session = New-PSSession -Credential $pp;

$Destination = "C:\Dest\"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Destination -Force

$HK = "\\servername\d$\Share\Install\ISO\HP\SPP\latest\packages"

if($site -eq 'HKG1') {$Location = $HK}
elseif($site -eq 'AMS4') {$Location = $AM}

NET USE $Location /USER:$User $Password
Copy-Item -Path $Location -Destination $Destination -recurse -Force
net use * /delete /y
Remove-PSSession $session
```

If I give /USER:$User $Password it gave me the 87 error, if I don't use it, it works BUT only when I ran on the server locally. If I ran from rundeck it needs the authentication.

So How can I create a proper ps-session or what is the issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can copy any item using the [copy file step](https://online.rundeck.com/plugins/copy-file-step).

Comment: This doesn't work from remote location only if it is located on rundeck.